# Cannot display image in SubDomain Apache XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, xampp, lamp, lampp

I have a php application, I access it usually using:

`localhost/my-site/public`

I'd like to use a sub-domain, so something like:

`my-site.locahost/some-url`

I changed the `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf` with:

```
ServerRoot "/opt/lampp"
Include "httpd-vhosts.conf"
```

And the `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/project/my-site/public"
    ServerName my-site.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

I can now acces it.
But I cannot display any images.

I have a `NotFoundHttpException` when trying to display

`my-site.localhost/resources/images/logo.png`

the file exists in:

`/opt/lampp/project/my-site/resources/images/`

But I can see it when using

`localhost/my-site/resources/images/logo.png`

Any ideas?

Comment: You forgot the `/public` in the path...

Comment: thanks, that's it !
I should move my resources in public folder.

Answer (score -1):

You should write down the serverAlias :

```
<VirtualHost *>
        DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/project/my-site/public"
        ServerName my-site.locahost/some-url
        ServerAlias my-site.locahost/some-url
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The `ServerAlias` directive expects a host name only, and the syntax for `ServerName` is `[scheme://]domain-name|ip-address[:port]` according to Apache manual. This does not only not answer the question that was asked, it is also plain technically wrong on multiple levels.